# How to call HTTP post method using 2 digit port number?

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular5

I am trying to get response from HTTP POST method using the URL `http://localhost:80/signin`.

When I test this API in Postman, this works well.

But in Angular 5 application, it discards port number.

I am using the following code:

```ts
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',"accept": "application/json"});

let body = { "username": "xyz", "password": "abc" };

this._http.post("http://localhost:80/signin", body, headers);
```

How to call HTTP POST method with two digit port number?

Comment: Port 80 is the default HTTP port. It is not necessary to specify it when using `http://`, so maybe Angular/the browser just drops it. Should work nonetheless. Have you tried e.g. port 81, this needs to be specified and must not be dropped.

Comment: Are you just idly wondering where the port went, or are you actually having problems making the request and getting a response? Give a [mcve].